# .htaccess Rewrite mod not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get my htaccess file to use this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

to rewrite this url:

```
http://cheesecakebb.org/index.php?action=vn
```

Comment: rewrite to http://cheesecakebb.org/index/vn or something similar

Comment: @user3791747: Is this wordpress or some other PHP/CMS framework you're using?

Comment: @anubhava This is the htaccess from wordpress, yes

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^index/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]
```

When someone clicks `example.com/index/something`, it will redirect (invisibly to the user) to `index.php?action=something`

Comment: hmmm, with that exact code it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: oh I see, so actually I want it so that when you go to example.com/index.php?action=something it shows up as example.com/index/something